# Array skips over rows in sheet / removing duplicates with loop issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have only started using Apps Script for a few months and usually I can figure out why it's giving me error messages. But this latest one has me completely stumped and I cannot find anyone who has asked anything similar on here.

I have very simple code which retrieves data from a spreadsheet, loops through it to remove some values before pasting it back into another sheet. However, the loop keeps throwing up the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

After some digging I think I found the issue - the array I have extracted from the sheet is 3 rows short of what it should be.

So `var refArray = sheet.getRange("F5:F").getValues();` has the length 65 even though there are 68 rows in the sheet.

But what really puzzles me is that when I run `var len = refArray.length` it returns 68! So, for lack of better lingo, this confuses my loop as it cannot find the last 3 items and I get the above error (at least that's what I think).

I have tried extracting the data using
`var refArray = sheet.getRange(1,6,sheet.getMaxRows(),1)` but this also just skips over the last 3 rows. There is no particular reason it would skip these rows, and sometimes it only skips 2, so I don't think the issue lies within my data...

I can share a mock-up of my sheet and script if it helps, I have no clue why it is doing this or how to fix it!

Thanks already everyone.

**EDIT**

I may have been barking up the wrong tree as I just tried to replicate the issue in another sheet and the array seemed to be extracted correctly, but then the error popped up again when it started to loop. As I said I'm just dabbling in Apps Script so my loops are very basic. I'm just gonna add the full sequence below and see if someone can spot the error:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = s.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = s.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

function test() {
  
  // get archive Array
  var archiveArray = sheet2.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
  console.log("Array Check: "+archiveArray[0][0]);

  // get ref Array to loop through
  var refArray = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
  console.log("Array Check: "+refArray[0][0]); // length 29

  var len = refArray.length; 
  console.log(len); // length 29

  for ( var l = len - 1; l > 0; l--){ 
    for( var a = 0; a < archiveArray.length; a++) {
      if ( archiveArray[a][0] == refArray[l][0] ) {
        refArray.splice(l,1);                         // remove all duplicates
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("New array:"+refArray);
```

Comment: Show your code, especially the `for` loop part.

Comment: When the conditional is matched, the length of `refArray` would be reduced which gives you the mentioned error under some circumstances. You should better copy the array and perform `splice` on it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that when declaring "len" separately the value wouldn't change even if the array itself gets shorter, or is that wrong? Also, how do I "copy" an array? Would I just array.push each value into a new array?

Comment: What I am talking is the actual length, `len` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to use `array.includes()` method and create a new array instead of change existed one:

With a loop:

```js
var archiveArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var refArray = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'];
var new_refArray = [];

for (var val of refArray) {
    if (!archiveArray.includes(val)) new_refArray.push(val)
}
    
console.log(new_refArray); // output [ 'e', 'f' ]
```

Or with a filter:

```js
var archiveArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var refArray = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'];
var new_refArray = refArray.filter(val => !archiveArray.includes(val));

console.log(new_refArray); // output [ 'e', 'f' ]
```

The final code can be like this:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = s.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = s.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

function test() {
  var archiveArray = sheet2.getRange("A3:A").getValues()
    .flat().filter(String); // convert 2D into 1D and remove empty elements

  var refArray = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues()
    .flat().filter(String); // convert 2D into 1D and remove empty elements

  var new_refArray = refArray.filter(val => !archiveArray.includes(val));

  console.log(new_refArray);
}
```

Note: if you want to paste the result array back on the sheet it should be a 2D array. You can convert the flat array into 2D array this way:

```
new_refArray = new_refArray.map(x => [x]); // [a,b,c] --> [[a],[b],[c]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both suggestions and they run without errors, however neither of them has removed any of the duplicates within my array unfortunately.

Comment: They shouldn't remove anything. The point was to create a new array with non-duplicated values (the values that absent in the `archiveArray`). Both of the snippets give you the new array that contains the unique values. Only: ['e', 'f'] in this case. Which is the same as if you remove the values 'a', 'b' from the `refArray`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased that differently. What I meant to say is when I try these in my script, the new array is an exact copy of the original array, and it still includes the duplicated values.

Comment: I think it's could be because the arrays in your sample are 2D arrays. But the arrays in my snippets are 1D arrays. I can show how you can handle it if you want.

Comment: I've added to my answer the code that shows how to convert a 2D array into a 1D array with `flat()` method and remove from the array empty element with `filter(String)` method.

Comment: Ah, I get frequently tripped up by 2D/1D issues! Thank you, this was very helpful and  has solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  removes a element, adjust the index `l` accordingly:

```
refArray.splice(l,1);
--l;//adjust index by 1
```